# Binding ListView SelectedItem between two or more ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, listviewitem

I have a Dictionary that contains an `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Person>> MyDictionary
```

Now in my xaml, I'm creating an `itemscontrol` that uses the dictionary's key for an expander and the person's collection in a `listview` something like this:

```
<ItemsControl   ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Expander Name="expander" IsExpanded="True">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="MyString:"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <Expander.Content>
                                <ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">

                                    <ListView.View>
                                        <GridView  AllowsColumnReorder="True">

                                            <GridViewColumn>
                                                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Name"  Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn>

                                            <GridViewColumn>
                                                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Last Name" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn>
                                        </GridView>
                                    </ListView.View>
                                </ListView>
                            </Expander.Content>
                        </Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Now, as you can see it creates a collection of expanders and each expander has a listview within it's content...

I want to let only one listview have a selected item, how can I do it?

If I wasn't clear: I will have 3 `Expanders`, each one has 1 `ListView`, each `ListView` has 4-5 item's,  i want that when a user click on a `listviewitem` all other `ListViews` selected items will be unselected.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you subscribe to the selection event of each list view and call [UnselectAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.unselectall.aspx) on the others.

Comment: Hi oddparity, thanks for you answer, i will test it asap, however, I'm using MVVM and I'm trying to avoid writing any code beind on my control. I bet there's a way to bind the selecetd item. I'm sure it will also teach me more about binding. i guess that if your solution works, I will use it if I wouldn't find any other "cleaner" option.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have an idea to do this . Bind the SelectedItem of all the listBox to same SelectedItemProperty of ViewModel like

**>xaml here I have two ListBox whose SelectedItem is bound to same property of VM**

```
<StackPanel Height="500" Width="500">
        <ListBox Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList1}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}"></ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList2}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}"></ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

> xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel() 
        {
            StudentList1 = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            StudentList1.Add(new Student() { Name = "abc", Age = 20 });
            StudentList1.Add(new Student() { Name = "abc", Age = 20 });
            StudentList1.Add(new Student() { Name = "abc", Age = 20 });

            StudentList2 = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            StudentList2.Add(new Student() { Name = "xyz", Age = 30 });
            StudentList2.Add(new Student() { Name = "xyz", Age = 30 });
            StudentList2.Add(new Student() { Name = "xyz", Age = 30 });
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList1 { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList2 { get; set; }

        Student selectedStudent;

        public Student SelectedStudent
        {
            get { return selectedStudent; }
            set { selectedStudent = value; Notify("SelectedStudent"); }
        }
        public void Notify(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

> Student Class

```
public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope you got an idea .SelectedItem works on the basis of References when you will select one Listbox item the SelectedStudent property of VM will get updated and hence all othe ListBox SelectedItem will get deselected because they dont have this reference in there itemssource. **The power of MVVM :)**

**>Update**

```
Student selectedStudent1;

        public Student SelectedStudent1
        {
            get { return selectedStudent1; }
            set {
                  selectedStudent=null;
                  selectedStudent1 = value;
                  Notify("SelectedStudent1"); }
        }

Student selectedStudent;

        public Student SelectedStudent
        {
            get { return selectedStudent; }
            set {
                  selectedStudent1=null;
                  selectedStudent = value; 
                  Notify("SelectedStudent"); }
        }
```

Comment: Hi ethicallogics. thanks for your comment, i forgot to say that the same "Person" can be on two listviews at the same time, therefore, your solution doesn't help me.

Comment: you mean same object can be in both lists.SelectedItem compares the reference of object not value

Comment: Ok then Create different Properties for all the ListBoxes and bind them to their selectedItem and then in the setter of each VM property set rest of the property to null like i update the answer